# VB code : Import userform data to excel sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I wish to populate a vb code that can allow me to do the following function:

Below is my userform:

Condition 1: 
[image]

After I click the Add Stock button, it will upload the data I fill in the data sheet named as Inventory (A4:A6)

Red color will be auto generate once the product and the stock in field being filled.

For the stock available will be able to search through the whole data sheet in Inventory to sum up all the stock which is being added or the last amount of the stock available.

If inside Inventory sheet does not contain the product ( new product), it will auto show 0 or blank to the stock available field in userform.

Condition 2:
[image]

After I click the Add Stock button, it will upload the data I fill in the data sheet named as Inventory (A7)

The Inventory sheet should look like this after I submit click the Add Stock button:
[image]

I have no idea on this method on how to import the data to my Inventory sheet.

Thanks or the help in advanced

My code will be like this:

```
Private Sub Addstock_Click()

Dim lRow As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("Inventory")
lRow = ws.Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlRows, _
SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues).Row + 1

With ws
 .Cells(lRow, 1).Value = Me.ordernumber.Value
 '.Cells(lRow, 2).Value = Me.TextBox5.Value
.Cells(lRow, 3).Value = Me.supplier.Value
.Cells(lRow, 4).Value = Me.productname.Value
.Cells(lRow, 5).Value = Me.stockavai.Value
 .Cells(lRow, 6).Value = Me.qty.Value
 .Cells(lRow, 7).Value = Me.newstock.Value
  .Cells(lRow, 8).Value = Me.unit.Value
  .Cells(lRow, 9).Value = Me.amount.Value
 End With




End Sub
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish here... Because your code seems to do what you are trying to do... Could you be a bit more clearer on your expectations and issues?

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
Private Sub Addstock_Click()

Dim lRow As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("Inventory")
lRow = ws.Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlRows, _
SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues)

With ws
 .Cells(lRow.Row + 1, 1).Value = Me.ordernumber.Value
 '.Cells(lRow.Row + 1, 2).Value = Me.TextBox5.Value
 .Cells(lRow.Row + 1, 3).Value = Me.supplier.Value
 .Cells(lRow.Row + 1, 4).Value = Me.productname.Value
 .Cells(lRow.Row + 1, 5).Value = Me.stockavai.Value
 .Cells(lRow.Row + 1, 6).Value = Me.qty.Value
 .Cells(lRow.Row + 1, 7).Value = Me.newstock.Value
 .Cells(lRow.Row + 1, 8).Value = Me.unit.Value
 .Cells(lRow.Row + 1, 9).Value = Me.amount.Value
 End With




End Sub
```